# Nuxt 3 & Electron Builder result in white page -> need electron + node.js to work

Tags: electron, native, nuxtjs3, electron-builder, nuxt3

I am building a native application using Nuxt3 and electron-builder.
Everything works when I use "yarn dev". Problems appear when I try to build the executable with electron-builder. Previously I tried making it a native application using nw.js, Tauri and others but they had their own problems I gave up on.

**Current outcome:**

- currently the generated exe displays a white blank page and has no errors except unsuccessful localhost connection attempt under network tab.

I have been kicking my head for a while now and seem to go around in circles.

**2 ways I have tried with electron-builder so far:**

- static output on "nuxi generate":

  - This one simply has an index.html I can give electron
  - everything seems to work **except** my outsourced api which is called through a proxy determined in nuxt.config.ts
  - the outsourced api is the main reason I am using the proxies as otherwise it gave cors errors and showed the specific endpoints on the client side as well.
- node application on "nuxt build":

  - This one does not have an index.html
  - I figured I have to make electron run node server ("index.mjs") and then make it load the url the node server is listening on -> works in my head :DD
  - currently electrons main.ts is configured to trigger preload.ts which runs the index.mjs ->

Preload.js

```
import {exec} from "child_process";

exec(`node .output/server/index.mjs`);
```

- console says it "Unable to load preload script:"
- Just for the sake of experiencing around I tried to use the preload code directly in main.ts ->

```
import {app, BrowserWindow} from 'electron';
import {exec} from "child_process";

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            devTools: true,
        },
    });
    win.webContents.addListener('did-finish-load', () => {
        exec(`node ./.output/server/index.mjs`);
    });
    win.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
})
```

- <- That resulted in no errors but it still unsuccessfully tries to connect to localhost and I don't know what else it could be.
- I need my electron to be independent of node.js as it has to work on other pc's as well.
- Other than the electron exe version when running my app simply using node -> all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere that there is an error related with the browser not recognizing the mime type .mjs, which is the one that is inside your .output/server/index.mjs, and main entry point of the application. I assume there is a place in your configuration or web server where you could define this mime type, but this requires some search I didn't do yet.